# Selecting last element of a list

Tags: mootools

Trying to select the last element of a list, I can't grasp the fundamentals of getElements, here is the html code

```html
<section class="main">
<ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    <li>Consectetur adipisicing.</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
</ul>
</section>
```

see this selectors:

```javascript
main = $$('section.main') // ok
main.getElements('li').getFirst() // .getFirst is not a function
main.getElements('li').getLast() // Object [ li, li, li, li, li, li ]
main.getElements('ul').getLast('li') // Object [ ul ]
main.getElement('ul').getElements('li').getLast().getLast() // li, Works!!
```

`getLast` should return the last element of an array, is it?

Comment: Can you share the HTML you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of mootools functions, when applied to an array, apply that function to every element in that array.

$$ returns an Array. so 'main' is an Array

getElements('li'), when invoked on an Array, invokes itself on every element of that Array. So now you've got an Array of Arrays. (actually, they're `Elements` objects, but let's ignore that)

main.getElements('li').getLast() returns you the last array in that Array of Arrays, which is why you're still getting an array instead of an element.

In other words, `main.getElements('li').getLast()` is equivalent to: `main.getLast().getElements('li')`.

Comment: `typeof($$('section.main'))` is returning an object here, not an array... is it the same in the moo dialect?

Comment: `typeof` always returns 'object' for an array in JavaScript. If you use 'typeOf' (Mootools' version of typeof) you will get back 'array'. The result of $$ is actually of type Elements: https://mootools.net/core/docs/1.5.1/Element/Element#Elements